# Win11: How much free disk space needed?

Tags: windows

Say folks, I am *struggling* with my Dell XPS Laptop.

It has a 500GB disk. I need.... every byte of that. I am constantly running out of space and needing to do cleanup.

I am stumped by 2 things:

1. The system just magically consumes disk space. When I rebooted 20 minutes ago, I had 16GB free. Now, without doing anything, I have 2GB free. What is going on?
2. Often, even after moving large amounts of data off the C: drive, the freed space is not reflected until I reboot (which is a pita)

So what is the word? Does it simply need %10 or something free all the time? (super painful)

Or ?

Comment: Free up (delete) temp files.  Move my Documents to a second drive. Get a much larger drive.  Your problem is hardly new or unique. Just do the obvious

Comment: Your title doesn't appear to really match your question. Can you perhaps EDIT your question to focus things a bit? Also, you have two specific questions that are different, even if they are related. This site deals in posts with single questions, so choose one of your questions and get rid of the other (or post it in its own post.

Comment: Clearing disk space is a pretty well-known and well-documented process. There are also questions about why disk space is being used up on this site and others. https://superuser.com/search?q=disk+space+[windows] Disk space is finite. You know how much space you have, and you can easily see how much space is available before you do anything. You need to control yourself, either by getting more disk space by any of various means, or by limiting what you install/use/create.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of programs and parts of your system that could be doing *anything* to consume space. Windows could be downloading feature updates or cumulative updates of varying sizes, Defender or antivirus programs could be updating themselves. Chrome could be deciding that it suddenly needs all your memory and causing your virtual memory to balloon. Many programs auto update. If you have games installed via Steam then it could be patching them. If you need every single last byte on a disk then if it is an SSD you could be working it into an early grave. Get a bigger disk.

Comment: Until you identify what is consuming your disk space, and provide details on what that service or application is, we cannot instruct on how to solve your problem. Getting a bigger might be the simplest solution but hardly the best solution since it likely won’t solve the underlying problem